# SerialPort DataReceivedHandler event not matching BytesToRead

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port

When using the following code:

```
    Private Sub DataReceivedHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)

    Dim sp As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort)

    Debug.WriteLine("DataReceivedHandler() - Data Received! number of bytes=" & sp.BytesToRead)
    Dim indata As String = sp.ReadExisting()

    Debug.WriteLine("DataReceivedHandler() - indata=" & TTSHelperFunctions.StringToHex(indata))

End Sub
```

What could cause `sp.BytesToRead` to indicate less bytes than when displaying the `indata` variable in debug output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debug.WriteLine() is pretty slow.  The serial port will continue to receive bytes while it executes.  So getting more bytes afterwards is a distinct possibility.

Comment: I refactored the code so that I loaded the data into local variables first and then output them via Debug.WriteLine().  This appears to confirm your theory!  What I don't understand is why Microsoft implemented it this way?  Shouldn't new bytes after this event wait in a separate buffer to be sent out the next time this event is fired?  Otherwise, isn't it possible for data loss to occur if you don't write your DataReceviedHandler() correctly?

Comment: I just saw this link.  It's from you right?  Pretty useful. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nb-NO/netfxbcl/thread/e36193cd-a708-42b3-86b7-adff82b19e5e

Comment: @gonzobrains: If data arrives between the time the `DataReceived` event is scheduled to run and the time it goes to read the port, why shouldn't such data be available to the application?  If the number of bytes one wants to read might be less than the number that are enqueued, don't use `ReadExisting`, but use some method that specifies the number of bytes to read.

Comment: @supercat  I think they should be available, but I didn't know if the SerialPort class was designed to allow such.

Comment: @gonzobrains: The `Read` method allows one to specify how much data to read.  I don't know all the corner cases for how `SerialPort` behaves if the `ReceivedData` event doesn't read all the data that's come in, so I always make sure that all data has been read and buffered by my parsing class before the event handler returns, but the individual read calls fetch only as much data as requested.

Comment: "Otherwise, isn't it possible for data loss to occur if you don't write your DataReceviedHandler() correctly?"  If you don't code correctly errors occur.